# Linux Mint Firefox Freezing all day long

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, freeze, linux-mint

I'll be on some basic websites and then firefox will just freeze. I click the x on the top right and it asks me to save and quit and that works. It closes. I then reopen. This cycle has been my firefox usage ever since going to mint 16 and I get this same issue on two different computers.

Why might it be freezing/locking up on me and how might I fix this? I like firefox and don't want to switch to chrome.

Also, the freezing happens on any and every type of site. Sometimes it's a youtube page, sometimes a google search result. Also, it will happen when I'm browsing sites like this one and not even gone to a video/youtube-type site yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any themes, plugins, etc. enabled.  If you turn them off and see if that solves the issue.  You can turn them back on one at a time until you isolate the culprit.

Otherwise, back up your bookmarks, etc. purge it and try reinstalling it.

Also check your memory usage.  I find Firefox to be a memory hog.  I've seen my firefox sucking up more than 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Firefox currently shows 52mb for me. Also, all plugins/addons are disabled. I'll try a purge a little later too.

Comment: Make that 520mb, not 52mb ram.

Comment: I've got several GB of RAM, only 3 tabs open and I'm currently using 544,672 K or nearly 544 MB.  I've got Gmail, IBM.com, StackExchange open.  I can easily ramp that to more than GB by adding some tabs and some media intensive sites.